# JdbcTemplate Query filtering

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Is there a Jdbc standard a way to filter the result return by a `jdbcTemplate.query` by `offset` and `limit`?

Also is there a simple way to transform a `ResultSet` (returned by a filtered query, like the above) into a `List<Map<String,String>>` result? Where the `List` is the row where the row values is stored in the `Map`? The row name being the map key and the row value being the map value.

Or there is a standard way of getting the rows out of a `ResultSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at JdbcTemplate#setMaxRows(int)

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setMaxRows%28int%29

This should apply a LIMIT/TOP.

--

I don't think OFFSET is so well defined, you may need to shoehorn that into your SQL statement in the relevant SQL dialect.

--

To filter the rows returned by JDBC driver and possibly build into Java user-defined object types look at check out the ResultSetExtractor and RowMapper.

ResultSetExtractor this is used to iterate over the ResultSet using ResultSet#next() this allows it to filter and skip based on business logic.  This method might make use of a RowMapper type to extract a single row of data it wants to keep, or it may do the extraction itself.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html

RowMapper this is used to make a single row into some valid, it could just be a List.  This method uses ResultSet#getWhatever(int).

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html

Then check the JdbcTemplate methods that take a ResultSetExtractor type as one of the arguments. This maybe a good example to start with:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[],%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor%29